# Save Workbook in current directory with title from cell

Tags: excel, vba

I download files where I need to rename them based on the name contained in cell A1. The file is already saved in the current directory, so what I am after is only to save to the current directory with the filename in call A1 and the extension ".xls"

Tried this code:

```
Sub SaveToRelativePath()
    Dim relativePath As String, sname As String
    sname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") & ".xls"
    relativePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sname
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath
End Sub
```

But the debugger reports an error on the last line: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath

Any clues to how this could be done?

Comment: What is the error message? Try a `Debug.Print relativePath` instead and see if the name is correct...

Comment: Could you please share error screen / text?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not specified, but in case you see:

[image: macro-free WB save warning]

It means you try to save a workbook with the above code as "XLS" (actually, not exactly, see below) - and that means a **macro-free** format. Excel warns you you'll lose the code.

One more issue - regardless of extension you code will save the book as **default** format for the Excel version you use (and that is XLSX or `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` for 2007 and perhaps future versions, I have 2007). As a result, you'll get on the saved file opening something like that:

[image: Incorrect format]

Solutions:

1. To avoid the 1st warning - save your initial workbook (i.e. that one where you keep the VBA code) as **Macro-Enabled** before running the macro.
2. Add proper format description to Save method - in your case that will be `FileFormat:=xlExcel8` - thus you'll get true XLS.
3. One more thing - to avoid aby compatibility alerts when saving file as XLS, add the `.CheckCompatibility = False` before saving. resulting code should be smth like that:

   ```
   Sub SaveToRelativePath()
       Dim relativePath As String, sname As String
       sname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") & ".xls"
       relativePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sname
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End Sub
   ```

However be careful - such construction will silently overwrite any existing file. Hope that was somehow helpful.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241279%28v=office.12%29.aspx - read more about allowed saving formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter! I'm using a very old Excel version (2002), so perhaps due to this I get this error in the debugger: